# How can I cast UDP streams in Perl?

Tags: perl, udp

My Perl script gets a UDP response that is built out of 2 integers + float numbers. The problem is that the UDP stream is one long stream of bytes.

How do I cast the stream into parameters using Perl?

Comment: Can you paste an example?  But your answer probably lies in [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) or [Convert::Binary::C](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Convert::Binary::C).

For more on pack and unpack see [perlpacktut - the Pack Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html).

With Convert::Binary::C, you pass in a C struct definition, and then you can easily extract the data members from the struct.